# django 1.8 - QuerySet generated include columns not in values

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I am trying to get a queryset displaying the average rate of comments.
The query looks pretty simple - although Django seems to add automatically an extra field created_at in the generated group by statement. Is there any way to remove it from the group by clause ? Is it there because of the default order by defined in the META class of the models ?

GROUP BY "authentification_antenne"."name", "review"."created_at"
instead of just GROUP BY "authentification_antenne"."name"

```
Review.objects.select_related(
'appartement__antenne').values('appartement__antenne__name').annotate(average_rating=Avg('rating')).query

SELECT 
"authentification_antenne"."name", AVG("review"."rating") AS "average_rating" FROM "review" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "staffing_appartement" ON ( "review"."appartement_id" = "staffing_appartement"."numero_contrat" ) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "authentification_antenne" ON ( "staffing_appartement"."antenne_id" = "authentification_antenne"."id" ) 
GROUP BY "authentification_antenne"."name", "review"."created_at" 
ORDER BY "review"."created_at" DESC
```

And the models.py

```
 class Review(models.Model):
     guest = models.ForeignKey(Guest)
     comment = models.TextField()
     rating = models.IntegerField(null=True)
     created_at = models.DateTimeField()
     imported_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
     appartement = models.ForeignKey('staffing.appartement', null=True)

     class Meta:
         ordering = ['-created_at']
```

Edit - I confirm the statement generated is correct when the created_at ordering is removed from the models.

Edit 2 - I resolved this by adding my values in an order_by clause to remove the default filtering

```
AirbnbReview.objects.select_related('appartement__antenne').values('appartement__antenne__name').order_by('appartement__antenne__name').annotate(average_rating=Avg('rating'))
```

Thank you

Comment: Yes, default ordering affects aggregation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by). I think, in case, explicit ordering is required. Can you please try: `Review.objects.select_related(
'appartement__antenne').values('appartement__antenne__name').order_by('created_at').annotate(average_rating=Avg('rating')).query`

Comment: That did not work be adding the appartement__antenne__name in the order_by clause did the trick ! thank you